# Fun with BULK INSERT SQL SERVER - type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

i am inserting data that looks like this:

```
   AA00000111   PSNH-OT J, SMITH    03/01/2011  10/11/1957  42  Male    Hartford    NH      Lorazepam   Benzodiazepines C
AA00000151  PSNH-OT BEN, HARRY  03/06/2011  07/18/1969  42  Male    Hartford    NH      Fentanyl    Synthetic Opioids   C
AA00000151  PSNH-OT URA, HARRISON   03/06/2011  07/18/1969  29  Male    Hartford    NH      Norfentanyl Synthetic Opioids   C
AA00000181  PSNH-OT WAYNE, GRIFFON  03/06/2011  09/01/1982  75  Female  Hartford    NH      cTHC (Marijuana metabolite) Illicits    C
```

with this bulk insert:

```
use RadarDataMining
go

BULK INSERT tblRadarsAC
FROM 'C:\PerfLogs\radars.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

and i am getting these errors:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 5, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 6, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 10, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 4 (date_tested).
Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

the fourth field type is `date`

it does not like my date field for some reason. i do not understand why. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What datatype is the fourth field?

Comment: @jnk what do you think the problem is?

Comment: This looks like patient data, be very careful about posting such on a public website, if you did not disguise the data you are in voiolation of the law in the US. I disguised the names just in case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a staging table to play with where the date field is specified as a varchar and not a date and see if you can bulk insert into that.  It is possible that you have some sort of nonprintable character in the field and thus it isn't a date to the bulk insert.

Once it is a table. do a select like this

Select 'XX'+field4+'XX'

If you see a space bewteen the the Xs and the date, you have an unprintable character.
If you want to know what the character is you can use the  ASCII () function.

Comment: but it is failing on the first row of data. do you see any problem with the first row?

Comment: If it has an unprintable charactor you can't see that. That's why I suggested bring it in as varchar where you can see if the data converts properly or do queries to find the unprintable character.

Comment: thank you. how would i find unprintable characters using sql?

Comment: is it possible that it does not like tab delimitted file?

Comment: YOur field terminator is a tab so that should be fine, but it is possible there is more than one tab between the fields before the data so that the date appears to have the wrong data in it.

Comment: i thought 2 tabs would just skip two columns. in any case thank you for your help. i did what you said. i will have the user figure out what the problem is with his data

Comment: If at all possible have him send you pipe delimted instead of tab delimited. Tabs are often characters in the fields themselves and then the import goes bad.