# Importing Excel files into SQL Server using a script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, import, import-from-excel

I have a bunch of Excel files that I want to import into a SQL Server database using a script.

I have imported one of the files (`BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part1_5.csv`) using the import wizard to setup the table correctly and then run the

```
delete * from dbo.temp
```

But when I run the following query I get the error:

> Bulk load data conversion error(type mismatch or invalid character for
>   the specified codepage)

My SQL code:

```
BULK INSERT [UK DATABASE 2014].dbo.temp 
FROM 'D:\The Data Warehouse.co.uk\BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part1_5.csv' 
WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
    FIRSTROW=2
)
```

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell me that table columns in table and text file are matching and same data types

Comment: may be there is an option of null values in text file .don't mention null values keep it blank instead of null and ROWTERMINATOR='<>'

Comment: Like i said all i did was import the file and delete all the rows from the newly created table so the fields in the table should be identical to the ones in the spreadsheet.

Comment: have you attempted this suggestion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490542/fun-with-bulk-insert-sql-server-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spe

Comment: Yes and it didnt work. I ended up writing a quick little command line tool in vb.net that does the job perfectly. But thanks for your help anyway